# Lost Income due to Work Injury

Tags: united-kingdom, workplace, compensation, injury

Assuming someone worked in the UK Oil and Gas industry on a platform on the UK continental shelf and were paid bonuses for work that they did offshore compared to onshore. Should this person sustain an injury, say chemical inhalation, that was not there fault whilst working offshore and had to be medevaced for medical care, and thus lose out on their offshore bonus for that trip. Would they be liable for compensation or at least the lost earnings?

Comment: There would be a right to compensation under the law of most U.S. states and under general maritime law, but I am not certain if maritime law would apply, or if UK law would apply in this case, which is a fairly technical question (basically, is an offshore rig legally an island or a boat?). I don't know what U.K. law would be in this situation although I strongly suspect that medical care and lost earnings would be covered although not necessarily a bonus which would probably come down to caselaw on the issue.

Comment: Some of the relevant U.K. laws are here: http://www.hse.gov.uk/offshore/law.htm and http://www.incelaw.com/en/knowledge-bank/maritime-labour-convention-and-the-offshore-oil-and-gas-industry jurisdiction depends upon whether the rig is mobile and whether it is in motion at the time of the injury.